# Why is my logistic regression classifier in Tensorflow not learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am learning Tensorflow by implementing a logistic regression classifier to classify a binary MNIst digit dataset. I am using tensorflow 1.13 as the code below shows

```
import tensorflow as tf
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True, per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.1)
s = tf.InteractiveSession(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
print("We're using TF", tf.__version__)
```

The dataset is as it follows:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
mnist = load_digits(2)

X,y = mnist.data, mnist.target
```

The following dataset has the following shapes

```
>> print("y [shape - %s]:" % (str(y.shape)), y[:10])
y [shape - (360,)]: [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1]

>> print("X [shape - %s]:" % (str(X.shape)))
X [shape - (360, 64)]:
```

From these shapes, I defined placeholders for inputs and variable for the weights (I hope they are correct)

```
weights = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([X.shape[1],1]), name="weights")
input_x = tf.placeholder('float32', shape=[None, X.shape[1]], name="input_x")
input_y = tf.placeholder('float32', shape=[None, 1], name="input_y")
```

Now I define the loss, optimizer and calculate the class probabilities as below

```
#predicted_y = <predicted probabilities for input_X>
logits = tf.matmul(input_x, weights)
predicted_y = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
probas=tf.argmax(predicted_y, axis=1)

#loss = <logistic loss (scalar, mean over sample)>
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=input_y))

#optimizer = <optimizer that minimizes loss>
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001).minimize(loss)
```

Then, I create a function to call the computation of the class from probabilities

```
predict_function=lambda vector1: probas.eval({input_x:vector1})
```

Now, I start to separate training and testing sets

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
```

Finally, I  train and test for each iteration

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

y_train_reshaped=np.reshape(y_train, (y_train.shape[0], 1))
s.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(5):

    #<run optimizer operation>
    s.run(optimizer, feed_dict={input_x:X_train,input_y:y_train_reshaped})

    #loss_i = <compute loss at iteration i>
    loss_i = loss.eval({input_x:X_train, input_y:y_train_reshaped})

    print("loss at iter %i:%.4f" % (i, loss_i))

    #My problem starts here
    print("train auc:",roc_auc_score(y_train, predict_function(X_train)))
    print("test auc:",roc_auc_score(y_test, predict_function(X_test)))
```

My problem with the above code is that, although I can see that the loss decreases at each iteration, the ROC metric remains the same. The output of this loop is something as follows:

```
loss at iter 0:0.6820
train auc: 0.5
test auc: 0.5
loss at iter 1:0.6712
train auc: 0.5
test auc: 0.5
loss at iter 2:0.6606
train auc: 0.5
test auc: 0.5
loss at iter 3:0.6503
train auc: 0.5
test auc: 0.5
loss at iter 4:0.6403
train auc: 0.5
test auc: 0.5
```

By printing the output of predict_function(X_train) or predict_function(X_test), I see that the prediction is always 0. Therefore, there is something I may not be understanding or not doing correctly. What am I missing here?

**EDIT:** I also tried increasing the learning rate to 0.1 and number of iterations to 50000 as suggested, the loss turns out to zero very fast, but both train and test AUC are 0.5, meaning that the classifier is predicting just one class. I am sure that is something wrong with my code, what exactly it would be?

Comment: The loss is going down, albeit slowly. You could try increasing the learning rate. Far more importantly, 5 iterations is _nothing_, you will need a lot more to see results. Try 500 or so for a start.

Comment: @xdurch0 I increased the learning rate to 0.1 and iterations to 5000 and the problem remains. The weird thing is that the loss turns out to zero very fast, but the classifier keeps predicting the same class both for training and testing data. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The input to the auc score function might just be wrong. The way I understand it, you should be providing the probabilities (i.e. `predicted_y`, the softmax output), but you are providing the "hard" classes (argmax of softmax)

Comment: @xdurch0 problem solved ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different mistakes here:

```
predicted_y = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
probas=tf.argmax(predicted_y, axis=1)
```

The first is that, since your `y` is not one-hot encoded, you should not use `softmax`, but `sigmoid` (something you correctly do in your `loss` definition); so, the first line should be

```
predicted_y = tf.nn.sigmoid(logits)
```

The second line, again since your `y` is not one-hot encoded, does not do what you think it does: since your predictions are single-element arrays, the `argmax` is by definition 0, so you don't get the correct conversion from probabilities to hard predictions (which hard predictions, in any case, are not used for calculating ROC - you need the probabilities for this).

You should drop `probas` altogether, and change your `prediction_function` to:

```
prediction_function=lambda vector1: predicted_y.eval({input_x:vector1})
```

That way, and for `learning_rate=0.1`, AUC goes to 1.0 from the very first iteration:

```
loss at iter 0:0.0085
train auc: 0.9998902365402557
test auc: 1.0
loss at iter 1:0.0066
train auc: 1.0
test auc: 1.0
loss at iter 2:0.0052
train auc: 1.0
test auc: 1.0
loss at iter 3:0.0042
train auc: 1.0
test auc: 1.0
loss at iter 4:0.0035
train auc: 1.0
test auc: 1.0
```

and you get correct predictions for `X_train`:

```
np.round(prediction_function(X_train)).reshape(1,-1)
# result:
array([[0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0.,
        1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.,
        1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.,
        0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1.,
        0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.,
        0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.,
        1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1.,
        1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.,
        1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.,
        0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.]],
      dtype=float32)
```